# How to implement IVsStatusbar when making a Visual Studio Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a visual studio add-in, and one of the things I will need to do is interact with the status bar.  According to [MSN: Status Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166795%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it should be a fairly straightforward process.  However, I cannot get it to resolve properly on the `IVsStatusbar` object.

The example suggests following a pretty standard process such as:

```
    IVsStatusbar StatusBar = (IVsStatusbar)GetService(typeof(SVsStatusbar));
```

But Visual Studio will not resolve the reference and tells me `IVsStatusbar` does not exist.  If I right-click to auto-resolve, it will just tell me to generate a new class for it.

I know it requires `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop` which I added, but still no luck.  I have tried v 10.0 and v 11.0 of the dll, but neither have worked.  Does it no longer exist in the namespace?  Or is there another reference / object I should be using?

I should have all of the references I need:

```
    using System;
    using Extensibility;
    using EnvDTE;
    using EnvDTE80;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
    using System.Resources;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Globalization;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference all of the versions of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.xx.dll, not just one of them. Rather than change interfaces over time, they create a new assembly with *added* interfaces which the services implement in addition to the previous versions.

Edit: Note that this only applies to the Interop assemblies. For other assemblies, such as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, you only need to reference version 10.0 (for a Visual Studio 2010 or 2010+2012 extension) or version 11.0 (for a Visual Studio 2012-only extension).

Comment: Ah, so I take it I would need the versions from 2005 and 2008 as well?

Comment: Yes, `IVsStatusBar` is defined in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll` introduced with Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Sure enough!  Thanks for your help, I'm afraid I would have been beating my head against the wall on this one.