# Visual Studio 2013 C# The type or namespace name IVSStatusBar could not be found

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, statusbar

I am trying to add a status bar to an already working application. I'm using Visual Studio 13, WPF, C#.

`public void SetStatusBar(string text)
{ 
IVsStatusbar statusBar = (IVsStatusbar)GetService(typeof(SVsStatusbar));
}`

I get these errors:
The type or namespace name 'IVsStatusbar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The name 'GetService' does not exist in the current context
and the first message again for 'SVsStatusbar'

I have the most recent SDK.  My using statements are:

```
using System
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;
```

What am I missing? This shouldn't be so difficult to find.

Comment: You are probably missing the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.

Comment: `IVSStatusBar` is [the interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.aspx) defined in the namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop` in the assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll`. And 1)I do not see this namespace in your using directives 2) The assembly that contains it is doubtfully [referenced by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) in standard WPF project template.

Comment: Some additional info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678056/how-to-implement-ivsstatusbar-when-making-a-visual-studio-add-in

Answer (score 0):

You need a using for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop`

The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar(v=vs.110).aspx) should provide any more information you might need.

Comment: I already tried that before I posted.  Sorry, I should have mentioned it.  When I type in using and Microsoft, there is no intellisense for VisualStudio.  I cannot add this through using.  I redownloaded the SDK and it still did not show up.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  I needed to click on References, add reference, choose extensions and add it there.  Then, I was able to declare it with 'using'.

Answer (score 0):

IVsStatusBar is defined in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll` Add this name space.

Please refer to this page [How to implement IVsStatusbar when making a Visual Studio Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678056/how-to-implement-ivsstatusbar-when-making-a-visual-studio-add-in)

Comment: I originally used that page.  I do not have Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.  I can't find on Microsoft's site how to install this component.

Comment: what do u mean you cant find. you need to add (Interop.dll) reference to the project and add that to your namespace in the code